# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Javascript:

```
function insertSmiley(a) {
    var $img = $(a).children('img');
    $("#message").insertAtCursor(($("#message").data("wbb").options.bbmode) ? $("#message").data("wbb").toBB($(a)): $(a).html());
    return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" onClick="return insertSmiley(this)"><img src="{smiley.SMILEY_IMG}" width="{smiley.SMILEY_WIDTH}" height="{smiley.SMILEY_HEIGHT}" alt="{smiley.SMILEY_CODE}" title="{smiley.SMILEY_DESC}" class="sm"/></a>
```

Can somebody tell me the error?

Here is complete html:
http://pastebin.com/bvSb7chV

Comment: It looks like insertAtCursor isn't in the jQuery documentation.  Does it work elsewhere for you?

Comment: What specific piece of code throws this error?  What isn't defined?

Comment: *What* function is "not defined"?  What is the ***exact*** error message?  What's `insertAtCursor`?  Did you load that plugin?

Comment: It was the document.ready thing, like in the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared function inside document.ready, just move it outside of document.ready.